# How to run a specific node Project from a Nested Project repository

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I have a serverless node project repository which contains multiple API lambdas and trigger lambdas there.

The project structure looks like this.

```
-node_modules
-src
  - API
    - searchApi
      -app.js
      ...
    - restoreApi
      -app.js
      ...
  - triggerLambda1
    - handler.js
  - triggerLambda2
    - handler.js
-package.json
-serverless.yaml
...
```

So to run a particular api there, I'm running this npm script using nodemon and it works fine. `nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/Api/searchApi/app.js`

But now I need to run the trigger lambdas, So from the cmd I tried to directly call the handler file like this.
node src/triggerLambda1/handler.js
But the module imports are failing like below.

```
(node:24232) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Git Repos\dp-dm-digital-archive-serverless\src\triggerLambda1\handler.js:2    
import IndexingService from './service/indexingService';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

As it suggest, I tried by adding "type": "module" to package.json. But didn't work either.

But this is the correct structure to deploy the code remotely to AWS. And in remote, it's working fine. But I need a way to test it locally as well. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure both API and lambda are in module ?, I think you have api in commonJS and lambda in module